# how to fixed this ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') in react js

Tags: reactjs

```
const Cart = ({ cartItems }) => {
  return (
    <div className="cart-items">
      <div className="cart-items-header">Cart Items</div>

      {cartItems.length === 0 && (
        <div className="cart-items-empty">No items are added.</div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: It means that `cartItems` is `undefiined`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `cartItems` its undefined. For preventing this kind of error, its better to check whether `cartItems` is undefined or not. So Try this :

```
const Cart = ({ cartItems }) => {
  return (
    <div className="cart-items">
      <div className="cart-items-header">Cart Items</div>

      {cartItems && cartItems.length === 0 && (
        <div className="cart-items-empty">No items are added.</div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ploppy said in one of the comments, it simply means that cartItems is undefined.
You now have 2 options

1. Ternary operator option:
   In the same ternary operator you are currently using you can check if cartItems is undefined BEFORE accessing its length. Indeed it solves the problem but cannot be considered best practice.

```js
    const Cart = ({ cartItems }) => {
      return (
        <div className="cart-items>
          <div className="cart-items-header">Cart Items</div>
          { cartItems && cartItems.length === 0 && (
             <div className="cart-items-empty">No items are added.</div>
          )}
        </div>
      )
}
```

2. TypeScript option:
   Another option would be to convert the codebase you are currently using into a TypeScript project to handle in the most efficient way type errors you might encounter.

- [TypeScript React Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react.html)
- [Migrate a React App to TypeScript](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-migrate-a-react-app-to-typescript/)

I've made a simple CodeSandbox to show you how Type management is handled in your case.
[TypeScript codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-cart-iis7u?file=/src/App.tsx)